# JQuery open specific tab in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, tabs

On my site thanks to a small script I can open a tab directly from another page.

But even though the script places me in the right tab, the content remains invisible, i.e. all white.

In reality the contents of the tab are visible in inspection.

I want to open a specific tab directly from another page.

```js
jQuery(window).load(function() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    var href = window.location.hash;
    if (href && jQuery('a' + href).length && jQuery('.post-3167 .nav.nav-tabs').length) {
      jQuery('.post-3167 .nav.nav-tabs .nav-item').removeClass('active');
      jQuery('.post-3167 .tab-content .tab-pane').removeClass('active')
      jQuery('a' + href).parent().addClass('active');
      jQuery(jQuery('a' + href).attr('href')).addClass('active');
    }
  }, '1000');

});
```

Comment: What is this weird construct? `jQuery(jQuery('a' + href).attr('href'))` You want to access the `href` of the `a` with the `ID=somehash` ? Please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and add a [mcve] using rendered HTML and relevant frameworks from CDN

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `show` class to display the tab content and ensure that the `active` class is applied correctly.

```js
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var href = window.location.hash;
    if (href && jQuery('a[href="' + href + '"]').length && jQuery('.post-3167 .nav.nav-tabs').length) {
      jQuery('.post-3167 .nav.nav-tabs .nav-item').removeClass('active');
      jQuery('.post-3167 .tab-content .tab-pane').removeClass('active show');
      jQuery('a[href="' + href + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
      jQuery(href).addClass('active show');
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply.
I tried with your code, the tab positions itself on the right one, but it doesn't open...
Other advice?
Thank you.